# opening a python file from input stored in a variable

Tags: python, variables, user-input, readfile

I am trying to get my program to open and read a text file from what the user inputs stored in the `file_name` variable, but it doesn't seem to read anything, but does print "File is now open".

```
def open_sn_file(self):
    while True:
        file_name = input("Please enter a file name or enter 'done' to exit the program: ")

        if file_name == "done":
            print("Bye.")
            break

        try:
            with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
                file.read()
                print("File is now open.")
```

I tried so many things, still getting the same problem. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Why do you think that it doesn't read anything?

Comment: Your code works perfectly, it simply does nothing.  You read the contents of the file, then you throw it away.  Presumably, you want to store the return from `file.read()` into a string, or maybe just `return` it.  What you have is the equivalent of writing the statement `3`.  It's valid, but does nothing.

Comment: _but it doesn't seem to read anything_ Yes it does.  It reads the file, and then proceeds to do **absolutely nothing** with the contents of that file.  Were you expecting the file contents to be printed, or something?

Comment: you don't print anything, you should print(file.read())

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first of all, you would need an `except` or `finally` after `try`.
Then, it is also better and cleaner to close the file after you are done with, as implemented below. Also, if you want to output the contents of the file in the console, you need to just print it, as done below. The following code below worked successfully for me:

Like this:

```
while True:
    file_name = input("Please enter a file name or enter 'done' to exit the program: ")

    if file_name == "done":
        print("Bye.")
        break

    try:
        with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
            print("File is now open.")
            print(file.read())
            file.close()
    except:
        print("An exception occurred")
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to use try except block when using context managers (with statement) as they have exception_handler defined inside them.

Your program run correctly it is reading file to the buffer but you didn't say anywhere you want to see what is inside. For example put file.read() as print argument and you will see some output in console